# WkHtmlToPdf library Arabic characters squared with italic fonts

Tags: java, utf-8, wkhtmltopdf

I am using `WkHtmlToPdf` to convert html pages which may contain Arabic text to pdf documents it's working fine but when using italic fonts with Arabic text it's displayed as squares as it's not finding the font and this is not for all fonts when using `Noto Naskh Arabic` it's working like a charm I am using V 1.1.12-RELEASE BYT. so Any ideas ?

**Edit:**
This issue is also happening in windows only on linux it's also working fine.

Comment: It seems that the system font you are depending on does not have an italic variant on Windows. You may need to load a web font that is known to have all the variants you need.

Comment: Yeah i guess this was the issue as it's working fine on Ubuntu urw-fonts I think, but i need it to work on windows